# Why I don't see LEADER badge on server?

Tags: linux, consul, consul-health-check

I have 3 consul servers in cluster. They were recovered from outage. Now they are running. Everything works. I checked with API who is leader, and I found it out.
But weird thing - I don't see LEADER badge in UI. Morover I see "No service checks" on each server.
I tried to restart each server, but it didn't help. How to fix it?

[image: Consul UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leader badge is shown under the Nodes view in the UI, not the Services view.

[image: Consul leader shown in Nodes view of Consul UI]

Aside from the built-in Serf health check, the Consul servers do not have any additional service checks associated with them.